# SQL Lower Bound?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to write a sql query that returns all values greater than or equal to x and also the first value that is not greater than x.

For example if we have a table containing values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and x is 3, I need to return 2, 3, 4, 5.

The fact that my example includes evenly spaced integers does not help because my actual data is not as cooperative.

Is this even possible or am I better off just getting the entire table and manually figuring out which rows I need?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

union is your best bet.  paste together the set of all values greater than x, and the largest value less than x.  Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT n FROM table WHERE n > $x ORDER BY n DESC
    UNION SELECT n from table WHERE n < $x ORDER By n DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me by 30 seconds. And you got the LIMIT syntax right. :-)

Comment: Can you fix your > to a <?

Comment: @mjr: Yeah, that's a kind important typo catch.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT <columns>                   -- you want in the result
FROM tableX
WHERE columnX >=
      ( SELECT MAX(columnX)
        FROM tableX
        WHERE columnX < @x         -- @x is the parameter, 3 in your example
      ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn >= 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn < 3 ORDER BY MyColumn DESC LIMIT 1
```